# Slurm like alternative for localhost

Tags: linux, scheduling, application

I have resources (e.g. GPU) I can only use once at a time. When performing experiments I always need to know on time of a batch files creation, what experiments I want to execute in the future. But I am a person who likes to change its mind, but I hate to quit jobs.

Is there something like Slurm, that runs only on one machine, which I can pass jobs to a queue and remove them if necessary?

I am looking for applications that either work on GPU load (in contrast to batch/at that works on CPU load) or executes the jobs sequentially. This means that only one job runs at a time on one resource (GPU) and the next one starts when the execution of the previous job finished.  I also want to be able to manage the queue in order to give jobs a higher priority or delete them.

Comment: `batch`?  It's _very_ simple, and nothing like SLURM, but it'll be installed already.

Comment: with atd (batch etc.) I can only set a load threashold for the cpu, but not for the gpu. Furthermore I found no solution for executing a queue sequentialy (Job 1 finishes, Job 2 starts, ...)

Comment: For sequential jobs, submit them as one single job.  No, you can probably not get `batch` to care about the GPU, only the general system load.

Comment: But I dont want to add them as a single job. This does not provide any advantage compared to a batchfile.

Comment: Hmm... If you want to run jobs sequentially, then why bother with SLURM?

Comment: Sounds like "I want this to run whenever any currently running job finishes" and ideally "I want to manage the things which are queued up waiting for the resource to become available", is that a correct characterization? Do you have full control over the jobe, i.e. can you require all of them to agree on a voluntary lock or something like that?

Comment: @tripleee: exactly! added the question according to your assumptions.

Comment: @Kusalananda: i don't want to bother with Slurm, that is why I want an alternative. With Slurm I also (as I would like to have) have one job per resource (at least the implementations that I know).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that perfectly fits my needs. I have the issue, that I have only one GPU, but want to have a queue to add jobs to, see their status and, if needed, delete it from the queue again.

After some research on Google, I found [task-spooler (tsp)](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/). With this command-line tool, it is fairly easy to add jobs to the queue and follow their results. So far I only use one queue, but it is also scale-able to more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the only user on the machine, then `hyper-shell` (https://hyper-shell.readthedocs.io) has the capabilities you need. You can run the `hyper-shell cluster` as a login item (or just keep it in the background) and use PostgreSQL as the backend database. For a single machine (especially single resource - 1 job at a time), this is an easy replacement for SLURM and is cross-platform.

You can submit jobs one at a time (like `sbatch`) using `hyper-shell task submit`, `squeue` would be something like `hyper-shell task search --remaining`.

Lot's of choices as far as configuration, logging, etc. But the basic launch of the scheduling service would be something like,

```bash
hyper-shell cluster -N1 --forever --max-retries=2 --capture
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `hyper-shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to have the jobs run through a simple queue manager of your own?

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! mkdir /tmp/my_gpu_lockdir; do
    sleep $((RANDOM))
done

trap 'rmdir /tmp/my_gnu_lockdir' ERR EXIT

.... your actual task here ...
```

Comment: I would prefer that the queuing system takes care of that. Additionally, I can not see weather this is still pending, I can't change the priority and so on.. But a good quick-shot.

Comment: You could perhaps wrap this with `batch` to have the job resubmit itself if the lock folder exists, and then use the regular `atq` / `atrm` for managing the queue.